# Can/should I use OSS ads on my own blog/site?

Tags: discussion, advertising, open-source-advertising

I really like the StackOverflow OSS ads, and I'd like to support the projects that managed to earn a slot. Can I put the ads on my own site or blog?

I'd imagine simply putting http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250 in an iFrame, but I want to make sure I'm not breaking any rules first :)

Comment: In contrast with Pekka's concern, I bet most project owners would love you to do so. Anyway, don't hesitate to re-use our AnkiDroid ad in any way you want :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<cent><cent>`

I think you should definitely talk to the project owners first. It's a nice offer but I'm sure they will want to know what environment their ads are being shown in.

`</cent></cent>`

You could try setting up a Meta question (including a link to your site) and asking those who put up the ads to leave a message whether they want their ad being shown or not.

Another thing to be aware of, using the SO iframe might cause confusion on the SO end when views and clicks are analyzed, so you should talk to the management as well.

Maybe talking to individual ad owners and copy+pasting their banners (bypassing SO's mechanisms entirely) is the best way, albeit the most bothersome for you.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Would be a shame, though... If I use an iFrame, I have no control over the ads shown and I would never be able to ask the owners first. I'm lazy, too: I don't want to have to copy images around. 

Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Your wish is my command:

[StackAd - An Easy Way to Display Open-Source Ads on Your Site/Blog](https://stackapps.com/questions/741/stackad-an-easy-way-to-display-open-source-ads-on-your-site-blog)

Comment: +1 Very, very nice! Are the concerns raised in my answer already addressed by this somehow, or would I, planning to use this, still have to talk to the ad owners to see whether they're okay with their ads being shown on my site?

Comment: @Pekka: Unfortunately, yes. But you have permission for my 2 ads :)

Comment: thanks :) But I was asking on a more general note, I don't have a site to build them in to at the moment. Maybe this would be worth talking to the SO team about - maybe introduce a keyword the ad maintainers should enter that explicitly allows showing them on 3rd party sites? Don't know, just thinking aloud.

Comment: @Pekka: Maybe there's some way they can be mirrored somewhere.

Comment: @Pekka: Now that all ads are hosted on `imgur`, this should not be a problem.